# Memoir class and textblock configuration for A4 paper

Tags: memoir

I'm using the `memoir` class to write my master thesis that should be printed on A4 paper. Altough I'm quite happy with the configuration I did for many aspects of the document, I'm still confused with the settings concerning the page size and the textblock size.

Now I just kepts this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]
```

My main question is: what's the best way to configure the size of the textblock in `memoir` ?

Should I use the `geometry` package ? Is there a good resource where I can observe common settings ?

In addition I'm a bit confused what the effects of `a4paper` really is: the margins are so large that it didn't seem to really consider it is a A4 paper size.

At the same time I'm wondering if 11pt is a good choice for a long document (100 - 150 pages) that will be read mainly from paper (I guess the font size is less important when you read from the screen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the memoir manual, it explaines all your questions. There is no need for the geometry package, memoir has its own macros for changing margins (the large default margins are LaTeX tradition)

Comment: Mea culpa, I read the doc in more details and figured how to do what I wanted.

Comment: How did you do this? I tried setting `\setlrmarginsandblock` and `\setmarginnotes` in the middle of my document, but I was not successful. I know it is a long time since you commented, but perhaps you remember?